# Google Analytics RegEx: Include all URLS with string "example" but exclude the ones with ".com/example"

Tags: regex, google-analytics

Hi I'm trying to filter some data in GA but facing some issues which I don't understand.

I want, from a list of URLs:

a) include all that have "retailer."
b) include all that have "/car/"
c) exclude all that have ".com/car/"

The goal is to capture all URLs that start with the subdomain retailer.
 and pages such as retailer.example.com/model/car/example1 or "retailer.example.com/model/car/example2" but not "retailer.example.com/car/something"

I've tried several options but can't seem to get what I need. Any suggestions?

Comment: What exactly have you tried, and what went wrong?

Comment: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034324?hl=en

Comment: I literally used the a,b,c filters and no results are shown. "include landing page containing retailer.", "include landing page containing /car/" and "exclude landing page containing .com/car/"

Answer (score 1):

This regex pattern should do the trick:

`retailer\.[\w.]+\.com/[\w.]+/car/[\w.]+`

In action: https://regex101.com/r/VSY37r/1